# How can I shuffle a list so the members of the list appear in different positions then the original list? Using DrRacket

Tags: racket, shuffle

I am trying to create a function that takes a list of "symbols" and shuffles the order of the symbols so they appear in a different order.

```
(define Deck
  (list symbol1 symbol1 symbol2 symbol2 symbol3 symbol3 symbol4 symbol4))
```

This is the Deck i want shuffled and i want the function to output something like this

```
(list symbol2 symbol1 symbol3 symbol1 symbol4 symbol2 symbol3 symbol4)
```

Comment: Can you use [`shuffle`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._shuffle%29%29) core function?

Comment: @MartinPůda when i try the shuffle function i get an error saying "shuffle: this function is not defined"

Comment: And did you call `(require racket/list)` before you used it?

Comment: What `#lang` are you working under?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle is a starting point for doing it yourself.

Comment: @MartinPůda i just added the call and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the `shuffle` function is built into the list library, which is built into the `racket` language. So, for instance, this program should run:

```
#lang racket

(shuffle (list 1 2 3 4))
```